# Excel VBA check if value is not in range

Tags: vba, excel

I have two ranges that should be identical (albeit they may be sorted differently). I'm trying to find any values in rangeA that are not in rangeB.

I'm able to find examples that show if values ARE matched in a range, but struggling to find anything if they aren't.

So far I have:

```
Sub Compare2()

    Dim test1, cell As Range
    Dim FoundRange As Range

    Set test1 = Sheets("Names").Range("A1:A5")
    For Each cell In test1

        Set FoundRange = Sheets("Queue & Status").Range("A1:A200").Find(what:=test1, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox (cell & " not found")    
        End If

    Next cell
End Sub
```

But it's showing all values as being not matched, when they are.

Comment: Do you really need done it with vba?

Comment: try changing test1 to cell in the Set FoundRange line.

Set FoundRange = Sheets("Queue & Status").Range("A1:A200").Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)

Tested and seems to work ok.

Comment: FYI `Dim test1, cell As Range` is declaring `cell` as a `Range`, and `test1` as an implicit `Variant`.

Comment: Are you really wanting to `LookIn` formulas, or are you trying to compare values?  (It won't matter which you do **if** all the cells are constants, but could cause problems if any of the data is calculated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Compare2()

    Dim test1 As Range
    Dim lookIn As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim FoundRange As Range

    Set test1 = Sheets("Names").Range("A1:A5")
    Set lookIn = Sheets("Queue & Status").Range("A1:A200")
    For Each c In test1

        Set FoundRange = lookIn.Find(what:=c.Value, lookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox (c.Value & " not found")
        End If

    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that too, but it worked so i posted anyways

Answer (score 0):

what:=test1 should be what:=cell (or even what:=cell.value)